# Explorer - canvas image editing issue

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, internet-explorer-11

I'm currently building a site that comes with a set of icons. They are white .png images with a transparent area. Each image is placed over a div whose background colour changes on `mouseover/mouseout` events.

I wrote a small JavaScript function that I can use to set the white portion of each .png to whatever the header background colour is so that the images blend in with the header and all you see is the transparent cut-away area change on mouse events - it's quite a nice effect.

So the white portion (not the transparent part) of the image should be changed to whatever the header background colour is, and the function works really great on Firefox, but for some reason doesn't work so well on Explorer (11).

Is there something I'm not seeing here? Here's the code that does the image editing - all I need to do is pass the `id` of the image and the hexadecimal colour string:

```
function setImageBg(
    imageID,
    imageColor
) {
    var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    // Get the red, green and blue values from the hex color
    // string.
    var redMix = parseInt(imageColor.substr(1, 2), 16);
    var greenMix = parseInt(imageColor.substr(2, 2), 16);
    var blueMix = parseInt(imageColor.substr(5, 2), 16);

    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;     
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

    // Get the image data...
    var pixelData = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    var imgData = pixelData.data;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imgDataURL;

    // Edit the image data.
    for (imagePos = 0; imagePos < ((img.width * img.height) * 4); imagePos += 4) {
        if (pixelData.data[(imagePos + 3)] <= 99)
            continue;

        imgData[imagePos] = redMix;
        imgData[(imagePos + 1)] = greenMix;
        imgData[(imagePos + 2)] = blueMix;
    }

    ctx.putImageData(pixelData, 0, 0);
    imgDataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

    document.getElementById(imageID).src = imgDataURL;
}
```

Like I say, it's great on Firefox - on Explorer all I see is the `div`, which still dutifully changes colour on mouse events. It's as though the entire image has been made transparent.

Any help would be greatly appreciate, much obliged.

UPDATE:

Ok, so I thought I'd cracked this...here's what happened.

The problem was that the image was loading and being edited in both IE and FF, when I noticed the image had loaded and rendered in IE I thought I'd found and fixed the bug...but after a refresh the image again disappeared.

I scratched my head over it for a bit then decided I'd wasted enough time on it and brushed it aside. Now everything else is in place and working, so I'm back to this and it's a proper head scratcher.

So - IE DOES actually load and edit/render the image, when you initially open the page that is. If you refresh the page, the image disappears...or does it?

I made some adjustments to the code, using alert()'s to try and diagnose the problem, I decided what I do was add some code to check the source file - instead of diving in and changing the pixel colours - I decided to check the image before it is being edited.

Seems that, on the second run of my function - the image loaded is completely black and completely transparent. All pixels have a value of 0!

What does this mean? There's definitely *something* there, but not what should be.

Is htis a cacheing issue? I messed about with it for a bit, it's odd that IE will load and display the image initially but will neglect to do so after a refresh, but Ff is fine. I tried a few tricks to disable cacheing but nothing works...so now I'm thinking, perhaps it's something else.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, I mean it's not a deal-breaker. Everything is fine without this single feature but it's a shame if I can't get it to work.

For anyone interested, here's the updated function after various changes/edits:

```
function setImageBg(
    imageSource,
    imageSrc,
    imageDst,
    imageColor
) {
    var img = document.getElementById(imageSrc);
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    var redMix = parseInt(imageColor.substr(1, 2), 16);
    var greenMix = parseInt(imageColor.substr(3, 2), 16);
    var blueMix = parseInt(imageColor.substr(5, 2), 16);

    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

    var pixelData = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    var imgData = pixelData.data;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imgDataURL;

    // Here's a change I made - on the first call of this function
    // when the page loads, all is good - on the second call after a
    // refresh this always returns on IE - it's as though the loaded
    // image (from file) is completely black and transparent
    // (everything is 0)...problem is the image file is never actually
    // altered - the loaded image is altered but the actual file never
    // changed - very odd...
    //  
    if (pixelData.data[0] == redMix) {
        if (pixelData.data[1] == greenMix) {
            if (pixelData.data[2] == blueMix) {
                document.getElementById(imageDst).src = document.getElementById(imageSrc).src;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    for (imagePos = 0; imagePos < ((img.width * img.height) * 4); imagePos += 4) {
        if (pixelData.data[(imagePos + 3)] <= 99)
            continue;

        pixelData.data[imagePos] = redMix;
        pixelData.data[(imagePos + 1)] = greenMix;
        pixelData.data[(imagePos + 2)] = blueMix;
    }

    ctx.putImageData(pixelData, 0, 0);
    document.getElementById(imageDst).src = canvas.toDataURL();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: if this is all running as soon as the page is loaded you might want to throw the guts of your function inside a `img.onload=function(){}` function, that way you know the image has loaded first. FF may just have the image cached while other browsers are having to load it.

Comment: I just cracked it, you are bang on. Appreciate the response.